# Selenium time execution of test

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

My Selenium test clicks on some elements of a page and executes javascript. How can I time this entire workflow? I am not testing the page load speed but rather how fast Selenium finishes execution of all the tasks I give it. I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and most thorough) out of the box solution is to use [Selenide](http://selenide.org/), which has a really nice (undocumented) feature that is able to give timings of page loads and components in a page.   But, you could add your own timer events to the Configuration methods of a JUnit or TestNG test.  Take this page as an example:  [How can we get exact time to load a page using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245062/how-can-we-get-exact-time-to-load-a-page-using-selenium-webdriver)

[image]